# Python - expected an indented block

Tags: python, error-handling, functional-programming

Just a beginner at Python trying to make a GPA calculator as a basic project, but getting an error in syntax: "expected an indented block"

```
import keyword

classes = int(input("How many classes do you need to calculate?: "))

gpa = 0.0

if classes == 1:

    credits = int(input("Please enter the amount of credit hours of the class: "))
    grade = input("What was the grade you have earned?: ")

    letter_points = letterGradeConversion()

    print(letter_points)

elif classes == 2:

    credits = int(input("Please enter the amount of credit hours of the first class: "))
    grade = input("What was the grade you have earned?: ")

    credits = int(input("Please enter the amount of credit hours of the  second class: "))
    grade = input("What was the grade you have earned?: ")


elif classes == 3:

    credits = int(input("Please enter the amount of credit hours of the first class: "))
    grade = input("What was the grade you have earned?: ")

    credits = int(input("Please enter the amount of credit hours of the second class: "))
    grade = input("What was the grade you have earned?: ")

    credits = int(input("Please enter the amount of credit hours of the third class: "))
    grade = input("What was the grade you have earned?: ")

elif classes == 4:
    credits = int(input("Please enter the amount of credit hours of the first class: "))
    grade = input("What was the grade you have earned?: ")

    credits = int(input("Please enter the amount of credit hours of the second class: "))
    grade = input("What was the grade you have earned?: ")

    credits = int(input("Please enter the amount of credit hours of the third class: "))
    grade = input("What was the grade you have earned?: ")    

    credits = int(input("Please enter the amount of credit hours of the fourth class: "))
    grade = input("What was the grade you have earned?: ")

else:
    print("The max number of classes on this application is currently 4")

def letterGradeConversion():
if grade == A:
    gpa = gpa + 4    
elif grade == B:
    gpa = gpa + 3
elif grade == C:
    gpa = gpa + 2
elif grade == D:
    gpa = gpa + 1
elif grade == F:
    gpa = gpa + 0
else:
    print("That is not a valid letter grade")
```

Not in code:

iuashd;alksdjas;kjdha;slkjaskljsakdljas;ljlkjf;lkjsFLKAJSD;KJASD;KLk;jaS'LKDJ;ldjk;'DH'AHKL'ASJKLASJKQIOWJWQOIH

Comment: It is a good idea to post the full stack trace as that contains information describing where in your code the error is occurring

Comment: BTW, you should try to reorganize your logic so you don't have all that repetition. See [Don't repeat yourself](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself). That will make your code more compact and easier to debug & maintain.

Answer (score 3):

Your function definition (everything after `def ... :`) has to be indented.

So

```
def letterGradeConversion():
    if grade == A:
        gpa = gpa + 4 
    ...
```

instead of

```
def letterGradeConversion():
if grade == A:
    gpa = gpa + 4 
...
```

Answer (score 0):

The entire block function definition for `letterGradeConversion` needs to be indented. Take a look at Python docs on indentation - https://docs.python.org/2.3/ref/indentation.html